# Возможно ли вывести переменную вверху страницы?

Tags: php

Возможно ли вывести перемнную на php вверху страницы, при том, что создана она будет внизу?

Проще говоря, возможно ли заставить работать такой php код?

**----------------index.php-------------**

echo $a;

$a="20";

**-----------------end page--------------**

Обычно echo переменной ставится после создания переменной, но возможно ли echo поставить на вверх, чтоб всё работало и вывелось число 20?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, разумеется. **Именно поэтому** весь вывод в нормальном коде начинается только после того, как определены все переменные.

Comment: какова цель данного порядка? возможно можно придумать обходной путь но нужно знать подробности задачи. в том виде как указан код он работать не будет, но я предпологаю задача чуть шире. тут нужно либо рефакторинг кода, либо искать другие способы.

Comment: зачем в принципе выводить переменную, которой еще не существует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Разумеется я не советую писать код плохо, это просто пример как можно реализовать подобную задачу в случае если нет нормальных решений без костылей. Само по себе использование переменной до объявления не является нормой ни для какого языка.**

```
    // создаем плейсхолдер для $a чем уникальнее тем лучше
    $a = ":placeholder_a"; 

    ob_start(); // начинаем захват буфера
    
    // какой-то код php ...   
    echo "before\n";
    echo "$a\n";
    echo "after\n";
    
    // где-то ниже задаем значение (для плейсхолдера)
    $a = 10; 
    
    // финальный вывод 
    $out = ob_get_clean(); // получаем буфер
    echo str_replace(":placeholder_a", $a, $out);  // подстановка и вывод
```

*Для чего это можно использовать, ну например нам нужно вывести какой-то текст и где-то в середине вставить его длину которую мы на момент вывода не знаем*

**вывод:**

```
before
10
after
```

Comment: Это будет работать, но для задачи вывода переменной в начале страницы - это костыль.

Comment: @NoSkill тут любое решение будет костылем:) Я отвечал на вопрос Возможно ли?

Comment: не уверен, что любое решение будет костылем. "если требуется вывести перемнную вверху страницы, при том, что создана она будет внизу" - наводит на мысль, что дизайн программы некоректен и его нужно переписать. минусовал ваш ответ не я, кстати... мой коментарий носит только предупредительный характер для автора вопроса, что применение ob_start() для данной цели - это костыль.

Comment: @NoSkill полностью согласен, дизайн кривой (поэтому и выделил жирным начало ответа), но цели и задач я не знаю, хотя спросил автор вопроса так и не ответил. а тот кто минусанул видимо не понял моей мотивации, до этого в шапке ответа не упоминалось что я думаю по этому поводу. я бы с удовольствием глянул на решение лучше моего с учетом сохранения условий.